# Does java use BODMAS?

Tags: java, calculator

At the moment, I'm trying to make a calculator using the java programming language. However, I need to know whether or not java uses BODMAS so that I'll know whether to make an algorithm that implements BODMAS or continue making the calculator. Does java use BODMAS?

Comment: BODMAS is basic rule of mathematics, its not dependent on any programming language.

Comment: Jhanvi's comment is wrong, ignore it. Also your question is misconceived; just because Java uses BODMAS doesn't mean you don't need to implement it yourself. Unless you are going to make your calculator write Java code and then compile it and run it, which would be slowest calculator ever!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's BODMAS not BOMDAS (division is before multiplication).

Yes Java does, there is also precedence rules that it uses about operators not included in BODMAS too

A full list can be found in the Java documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 2):

First, thanks for asking the question. I personally have never heard the term BODMAS. Now I know that it means :

```
B
Brackets first
O
Orders (ie Powers and Square Roots, etc.)
DM
Division and Multiplication
AS
Addition and Subtraction
```

So, I personally do not know language that does not support BODNAS internally. I however cannot understand how do you want to use this fact when implementing your calculator.